# PhysicsConnector issue

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

When I try sprite to connect to the body, they get a different coordinates.
Sprite follows the body, but they are slightly displaced.

I do the following:

```
mBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(mPhysicsWorld,POSITION_X, 
    POSITION_Y, 100, 0, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

    mPlayer = new Sprite(0.0f, 0.0f,100,100 mTextures.getPlayer());

    mScene.getChild(GameObjectsMap.GAMEOBJECTS_LAYER).attachChild(mPlayer );

    mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mPlayer,
                    mBody, true, true));

    mScene.registerUpdateHandler(mPhysicsWorld);
```

Why so occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the createCircleBody() method without coordinates. It should be the simplest one.